# I can't do anything with pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.

I can't use pipenv in Ubuntu18.04.
How can I fix it?

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: I use python 3.9.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open issue in the Pipenv repository: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5052.

From the discussion in the thread, it seems to pop up when there is an existing virtualenv that was created with the same directory path. The solution mentioned in the thread is to simply remove this virtualenv which fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the python virtual environment,

1. `python -m venv venv #  Creates virtual environment`
2. To activate virtual environment do `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Then you can install your packages using `pip install lib`

To deactivate virtual environment type `deactivate`